# append to request.sessions[list] in Django

Tags: python, django

Something is bugging me.
I'm following along with this beginner tutorial for django (cs50) and at some point we receive a string back from a form submission and want to add it to a list:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8q0C-C1js4&list=PLhQjrBD2T380xvFSUmToMMzERZ3qB5Ueu&t=5777s

```
def add(request):
if 'tasklist' not in request.session:
    request.session['tasklist'] = []
if request.method == 'POST':
    form_data = NewTaskForm(request.POST)
    if form_data.is_valid():
        task = form_data.cleaned_data['task']
        request.session['tasklist'] += [task]
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('tasks:index'))
```

I've checked the type of `request.session['tasklist']`and python shows it's a list.
The `task` variable is a string.

So why doesn't `request.session['tasklist'].append(task)` work properly? I can see it being added to the list via some print statements but then it is 'forgotten again' - it doesn't seem to be permanently added to the tasklist.

Why do we use this `request.session['tasklist'] += [task]` instead?

The only thing I could find is https://ogirardot.wordpress.com/2010/09/17/append-objects-in-request-session-in-django/ but that refers to a site that no longer exists.

The code works fine, but I'm trying to understand why you need to use a different operation and can't / shouldn't use the append method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why it does not work is because django does not see that you have changed anything in the session by using the `append()` method on a list that is in the session.

What you are doing here is essentially pulling out the reference to the list and making changes to it without the session backend knowing anything about it. An other way to explain:

- The `append()` method is on the list itself not on the session object
- When you call `append()` on the list you are only talking to the list and the list's parent (the session) has no idea what you guys are doing
- When you however do an assignment on the session itself `session['whatever'] = 'something'` then it knows that something is up and changes are made
- So the key here is that you need to operate on the session object directly if you want your changes to be updated automatically

Django only thinks it needs to save a changed session item if the item got reassigned to the session. See here: [django session base code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py) the `__setitem__` method containing a `self.modified = True` statement.

The `session['list'] += [new_element]` adds a new list item (mutates the list stored in the session, so the list reference stays the same) and then gets it reassigned to the session again -> thus triggering first a `__getitem__` call -> then your `+= / __iadd__` runs on the value read -> then a `__setitem__` call is made (with the list ref. passed to it). You can see it in the django codebase that it marks the session after each `__setitem__` call as modified.

The `session['list'] = session['list'] + [new_item]` mode of doing the same does create a new list every time it's run so its a bit less efficient, but you should not store hundreds of items in the session anyway. So you're probably fine. This also works exactly as above.

However if you use sub-keys in the session like `session['list']['x'] = 'whatever'` the session will not see itself as modified so you need to mark it as by `request.session.modified = True`

Comment: That situation is strange, because list += [new_element] works perfectly despite of the id of list is not changing...

Comment: You are right, I was not completely aware of why it worked that way, so made a small class similar to in django's SessionBase class and figured that the `__setitem__` method gets called every time an assignment is made to it, no matter if the reference of the item changed or not. That's why it works. I changed the explanation above to reflect it.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It's about how Python chooses to implement the dict data structure.

Long answer:

Let's start by saying that request.session is a dictionary.

Quoting Django's documentation, "By default, Django only saves to the session database when the session has been modified – that is if any of its dictionary values have been assigned or deleted". [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20211125125913/https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved)

So, the problem is that the session database is not being modified by
request.session['tasklist'].append(task)

Seeing the related parts Django's [Session base code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py) (as posted by @Csaba K. in an answer), the variable **self.modified** is to be set True when **setitem** dunder method is called.

Now, at this step the problem seems like the setitem dunder method is not being called with request.session['tasklist'].append(task) but with request.session['tasklist'] += [task] it gets called. It is not due to if the reference of request.session['tasklist'] is changing or not as pointed out by another answer, because the reference to the underlying list remains the same.

To confirm, let's create a custom dictionary which extends the Python dict, and print something when **setitem** dunder method is called.

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, globalVar):
        super().__init__()
        self.globalVar = globalVar

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        print("Called Set item when: ", end="")

myDict =  MyDict(0)
print("Creating Dict")

print("-----")

myDict["y"] = []
print("Adding a new key-value pair")

print("-----")

myDict["y"] += ["x"]
print(" using +=")

print("-----")

myDict["y"].append("x")
print("append")

print("-----")

myDict["y"].extend(["x"])
print("extend")

print("-----")

myDict["y"] = myDict["y"] + ["x"]
print(" using +",)

print("-----")
```

It prints:

```
Creating Dict
-----
Called Set item when: Adding a new key-value pair
-----
Called Set item when:  using +=
-----
append
-----
extend
-----
Called Set item when:  using +
-----
```

As we can see, **setitem** dunder method is called and in turn self.modified is set true only when adding a new key-value pair, or using += or using +, but not when initializing, appending or extending an iterable (in this case a list). Now, the operator + and += do very different things in Python, as explained in the other answer. += behaves more like the append method but in this case, I guess it's more about how Python chooses to implement the dict data structure rather than how +, += and append behave on lists.

Answer (score 0):

I found this while doing some more searching:
https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NewbieMistakes

Scroll to 'Appending to a list in session doesn't work'

Again, it is a very dated entry but still seems to hold true.

Not completely satisfied because this does not answer the question as to 'why' this doesn't work, but at the very least confirms 'something's up' and you should probably still use the recommendations there.

(if anyone out there can actually explain this in a more verbose manner then I'd be happy to hear it)

Comment: I rewrote my explanation above to be more concise and easier to understand. Hope it helps.